# Activerecord or SQL statement to find users where something very specific happens in the join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a User that have_many MyVersions associated.
A MyVersion is created every time the column "profile_id" or "state" are changed in User. MyVersion has these columns:

```
user_id, object_changed (profile_id or state), before, after
```

I need to find Users that where active and had a specific profile at a specific time. Meaning, to find all Users when this happens in its associated my_versions:

1. my_versions was created_at before a date AND where :object_changed is 'state' **And within that time range:** 
   1.1 THEN (is not AND) find the last one and only select the user if the value for :after is 'active'
2. my_versions was created_at before a date AND where :object_changed is 'profile_id' **And within that time range:**
   2.1 THEN find the last one and only select the user if the value for :after is '1'
3. Select only users that match both 1.1 and 2.1

EDIT 1: Apparently I'm getting closer but still not sure this is getting what I need:

```
active_user_ids = User.joins(:my_versions).merge(MyVersion.where(
  "my_versions.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) from my_versions WHERE
    user_id = users.id AND created_at < '2016-01-01' AND object_changed = 'state')
  AND my_versions.after = 'activo'")).pluck(:id)
```

Now I have all user IDS that were active at the time (do I?). Then I can do the same for the profile, but passing also the previous IDS to combine the results properly:

```
active_and_right_profile =
  User.joins(:my_versions).merge(MyVersion.where(
  "my_versions.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) from my_versions WHERE
    user_id = users.id AND created_at < '2016-01-01' AND object_changed = 'profile_id')
  AND my_versions.after = 1")).where(id: active_user_ids)
```

It doesn't look pretty and I'm not sure I'm getting what I describe above in the specifications. First tests appears to be right but I have many doubts because I don't understand some parts of the query:

- Apparently when I use "SELECT MAX ... where user_id = users.id" I'm requiring the top value for each user id. Is that right?
- If that's true, I'm getting and array of results and I'm passing it to the first created_at =. This means that if I have other versions outside of the scope of this query but with the exact timestamp, they will be in the results. Is that correct? That's relevant to me because few of those versions.created_at are being updated manually.

How does it look? Is there a way to make it better with only one query? Is there a way to avoid the problem of searching exact created_at values that I mention above?

Thanks!!

Previous attempts:
I tried this:

```
Class User...

scope :active_at, -> (date) {
  joins(:my_versions).merge(MyVersion.on_state.before_date(date)
  .where("my_versions.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM my_versions WHERE user_id = users.id AND after = 'activo')"))
}
```

But this create the folliwing query:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `my_versions` ON `my_versions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `my_versions`.`object_changed` = 'state' AND (my_versions.created_at < '2016-01-31') AND (my_versions.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM my_versions WHERE user_id = users.id AND after = 'activo'))
```

This is not what I need.

Comment: The sql query seems to match your scope, but not your informal specification. But how does the scope match your informal specification? And what would an sql query that you want look like?

Comment: Exactly! I tried that but is not working. That Query is the result of my scope but not what I need.

Comment: OK, but which sql query would you need?

Comment: I don't know the exact Query. I edited the question with more information that may be useful to help me. Thanks!